# Firmware Recovery for Dynamixel Motor

Tags: driver, recovery, firmware

I am using a [MX-106 Dynamixel Motor](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel/mx_series/mx-106.htm). For those who dont know about this motor, it is:-

**A module actuator which incorporates all the function needed for joint of robot**

It has a reduction gear + controller + driver + network = Dynamixel motor

Basically, the problem is that I can write to the motor using the required status packet but cannot read any response packets from it.

Things I tried:-

1. Checked my Hardware connections to ensure that proper serial communication is happening with the help of another Dynamixel motor
2. Checked my custom code for sending these data packets. It works for the second Motor.
3. Contacted the customer help and followed through standard procedures
4. Used the Dynamixel Wizard to check for Motor ID

I think the Firmware needs to be updated but that can be done by the Dynamixel Wizard only if the Dynamixel motor is recognized. Since no value can be read from dynamixel, the Wizard cannot recognize the motor id or device.

On the other hand, I know the motor ID since I am successfully able to write to the motor and the motor moves to that position.

Therfore, I believe, that the firmware can be rewritten into the motor using the motor ID.

**I need help in finding a way** to do that and the precautions I should take in order to prevent damaging the motor.

Please Help

Comment: Have you confirmed that the serial connection is working properly? Do you have other dynamixel's connected and working ?

Comment: @lxx Yes, I have confirmed it. Yes, I have another dynamixel connected and working properly.

Comment: If the firmware update protocol requires two-way communication, which is likely, it will still not work.  Moreover your assumption that the issue is with the firmware is probably amongst the least likely of conclusions on the evidence you have provided. I suggest that you simply replace it under warranty.

Comment: More plausible perhaps is that the output driver on the MX-106 interface is damaged.   MX-106T or  MX-106R?  Either way, this is not in scope for an SO question.

Comment: Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ - looks like a hardware problem to me.

Comment: note its nothing special in terms of hardware just a servo motor with a serial interface. Have you tried troubleshooting by swapping the motor positions ? Are you certain that your software is correct? Is your wiring correct ? Your haven't accidently swapped a lead or reverse the connector ?

Comment: @lxx They have different IDs. ID- 01 and ID- 02. The ID-02 is working fine with the same hardware and software. ID-01 is moving but isnt returning a status packet as ID-02 is. So, yes, the codes are correct.

Comment: Did you swap the other motor to the same position to make sure its not a connection problem or ground/power problem?

Comment: @lxx Yes, I ensured its not a connection problem

Comment: in that case a firmware update isn't going to fix a damaged driver or other electronics - what Clifford said earlier

Comment: Did you try using the R+ Manager?